How can I calculate the geometric growth ratio when three quantities are known?
I am trying to automate a portion of my analysis workflow which utilizes geometric progression.
I know the following three quantities:

$a$ - First term of the series
$z$ - Last term of the series
$S_n$ - Total sum of the series

I want to find the following quantities that will satisfy the known quantities:

$N$ - Total number of terms in the series
$r$ - Geometric progression ratio

By manipulating the formula for summation of terms in a  geometric progression, the following equation can be derived: $$ r^N - r  \cdot \left ( \frac{S_n}{a} \right ) + \left ( \frac{S_n}{a} - 1 \right ) = 0 $$
This an equation which can be solved numerically using a root-finding algorithm. This, I understand. However, I am not able to understand how I can implement the numerical approach so that the three known quantities are satisfied. I have played around with fsolve from scipy.optimize and I think this package will be useful.
Also, as a good estimate for $N$, this works: $$ N = \frac{S_n}{ (a+z)/2}$$.
What would be the right approach to tackle this problem ?

I fixed this problem by numerically solving the following two simultaneous equations for $r$ and $N$:
$$ r^N - r\cdot\frac{S_n}{a} + \left( \frac{S_n}{a} - 1\right) = 0$$
$$ z = r^{N-1}\cdot a$$
I used the  fsolve functionality: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html
The initial guesses for $r$ and $N$ were provided using the derivations outlined by John: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4985516/1168926.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The solution is to write down what you know and don't know. Let

$r$ be the (unknown) geometric progression ratio
$n$ be the (unknown) number of terms in the series
$a$ be the first term
$z$ be the last term
$S$ be the sum of the terms.

Then

Your series is $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1}$.
In general,
$$
a_k = r^k a_0
$$
$a_0 = a$; $a_{n-1} = z$
$S = (1 + r + \ldots + r^{n-1}) a_0$.

But suppose we leave off the last term! Then we have
$$
S - z = (1 + r + \ldots + r^{n-2}) a_0 
$$
Applying the geometric series formula, and substituting $a$ for $a_0$, we get
$$
S-z = \frac{1 - r^{n-1}}{1-r} a
$$
Hold that thought.
We can also look at
$$
\frac{z}{a} = \frac{r^{n-1}a_0}{a_0} = r^{n-1}.
$$
Substituting this in the prior formula gives
$$
S-z = \frac{1 - \frac{z}{a}}{1-r} a
$$
which we can adjust to get
$$
1-r = \frac{1 - \frac{z}{a}}{S-z} a =\frac{a - z}{S-z}
$$
so that
\begin{align}
r 
&= 1 -  \frac{a - z}{S-z} \\ 
&= \frac{(S-z)- (a - z)}{S-z }\\
&= \frac{S- a}{S-z }\\
\end{align}
Finally, now that we know $r$ in terms of the known values $S, a, Z$, we can compute $n$, for
$$
z = r^{n-1} a
$$
hence
$$
\frac{z}{a} = r^{n-1}
$$
so
$$
\log(\frac{z}{a}) = (n-1) \log(r)
$$
so
$$
\frac{\log(\frac{z}{a})}{\log(r)}+ 1 = n.
$$
Let's try this out with an example:
$a = 3, r = 2, n = 4$ gives the series
$$
3, 6, 12, 24
$$
with sum $S = 45$.
Our "known" data is $a = 3, z = 24, S = 45$. Using the first formula, we get
$$
r = \frac{S-a}{S-z} = \frac{42}{21} = 2,
$$
as expected. And then the second formula gives us
\begin{align}
n 
&= \frac{\log(\frac{z}{a})}{\log(r)}+ 1 \\
&= \frac{\log(\frac{24}{3})}{\log(2)}+ 1 \\
&= \frac{\log(8)}{\log(2)}+ 1 \\
&= \frac{3\log(2)}{\log(2)}+ 1 \\
&= 3 + 1 \\
&= 4 \\
\end{align}
so it all seems to work in practice!
By the way, a natural question is "What log are you using here? Log base 10? Log base 2? Natural logarithm?" and the answer is, "It doesn't matter which you choose, as long as you're consistent, because any of those logarithm functions is a constant multiple of any other, so the quotients end up the same!"

Thanks. I derived it myself and it works. I had done something similar earlier but I made the mistake in summation of terms exclusive of the last term which gave me wrong results.

Sorry. But I did some more verifications. For example , consider $a=0.5$,$z=7$,$S_{n} = 16$. This gives $r=1.72222222$ and $N=6$. All good. But, if you back substitute these values to calculate $S_n$ it leads to 17.372539 and not 16.

It actually gives $a = 0.5, r = 1.722222...$ and ...  $n = 5.85464...$, which you presumably rounded up to $6$. The problem here is that if you give a sum which is not the sum of an integer number of terms of any geometric series with those starting and ending values, then the formula will product garbage. It's the classic garbage-in, garbage-out problem.

In my analysis, I want to use arbitrary user inputs. Then, numerical approach would be the way to go. However, the previous derivations should work as good initial guesses. This brings me to the original question of how I can use the numerical root-finding approach.

I used your approach to give initial guesses for the numerical solution of two simultaneous equations. The error between actual and calculated is quite low and works in practice.

You understand, I hope, that for some initial data, i.e., some triples $(a, z, S)$ there is no finite geometric series with initial item a, final item z, and sum S. So "arbitrary user inputs" are going to lead to garbage. I have no idea what your "numerical root finding approach" is actually finding, but in general it's not a solution to the problem you posed, because that problem has no solution (in general). [The set of $(a, z, S)$ triples for which there is a solution is vanishingly small, or, in technical terms, has measure zero.]
